# How to get the coordinates of a drawn ploygon using angular google maps (AGM)

Tags: google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm working on a feature where the user should be able to draw a `polygon` and store the `polygon coordinates` into the system so I can show it later on the map. 
I implemented the drawing feature here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptjb9t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

but how can I get the coordinates "points(lat,lng)" of that polygon?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by listening to `polygoncomplete` event, from that you can get the polygon coordinates as shown below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
  const len = polygon.getPath().getLength();
  const polyArrayLatLng = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const vertex = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
    const vertexLatLng = {lat: vertex.lat(), lng: vertex.lng()};
    polyArrayLatLng.push(vertexLatLng);
  }
  // the last point of polygon should be always the same as the first point (math rule)
  polyArrayLatLng.push(polyArrayLatLng[0]);


  console.log('coordinates', polyArrayLatLng);
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iny9g2), references: 
[google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer)